# Does latest version of Umbraco CMS use asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I've heard that new version of Umbraco CMS will be completely rewritten and will be based on asp.net mvc?

Current version is 4.5 and as I see it is still based on ASP.NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like Umbraco 5.0 does/will:

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/about/roadmap/umbraco-50

I don't think the current version does though.

Answer (score 3):

Version 4.* of Umbraco curently uses web forms and any further updates to version 4 will continue on this model.
The Version 5 re-write is currently under development and is based on ASP.NET MVC 3 and is planned to be available sometime next year.